# Discrete variable, dummies with only one occurance; how do work with this in a regression?

Tags: regression

I am roughly running an OLS regression of prices and the number of network providers in cities in the UK.  Let $P$ stand for prices and $net$ stand for the number of network providers.  The frequency of $net$ is:

```
net   frequency
0        100
1        140
2        100
3        40
4        10
5        10
6        1
7        1
```

After generating dummies d0, ..., d7, for each state of $net$ (for example, d0 is equal to 0 when there are at least one company on the market and zero otherwise), I ran a regression of $P$ over d0,...,d6.  My question is not about this model per se, but about if it is correct in general to keep the dummies d6 and d7 given that they are equal to 1 only once.  Should I group d5, d6 and d7?  (that is consider d5+, a dummy for the case where there are 5 or more companies on the market), or the correct thing to do is to keep the given dummies as it is?   On the general model I am considering, the outcomes change a bit when I work with d5+ instead of d5,d6,d7.  Would you know a reference dealing with this situation?

Comment: I don't follow how your $net$ frequencies are related to the numbers listed & your dummies d0-7. If you have counts, why not use them directly as your covariate?

Comment: Sorry, I typed as a column of the frequences of each value $net$ takes.  Hence there are 100 cases where $net$ equals to 0, 140 cases where $net$ equals to 1, 100 cases where $net$ equals 2, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dummy variable that is zero for all but one observation in your sample, then your OLS estimates (for the remaining coefficients) should be identical to those you get when you simply drop that one observation. If you do include it, the residual for that one observation will be zero.

This means you need to be careful how you interpret your OLS results if you choose not to recode. You can also use the standard error for the coefficient on that dummy variable to test if that observation has a statistically significant impact on your estimation.

Finally, you can plausibly collapse the top three groups for the main analysis (as long as you have the other results handy and they are not too different.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Do you know any reference for this?

Comment: The economist David Giles extends the OLS results of Hendry and Santos to IV and stochastic Xs in http://web.uvic.ca/~dgiles/downloads/working_papers/ewp1106.pdf. I find his summary to be much more readible than the original paper, though only the first part will be relevant for you. He also mentions a working paper on this topic on his blog, but I have not found a copy anywhere.